# Definition of $\lim(x_n)\ne l$.

Tags: limits

$x_n$ is a sequence.

Definition of $(x_n)$ converge to $l$ is $\exists l \in \mathbb R,\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb N, s.t. \forall n\geq N,|x_n-l|\leq\epsilon$.

Definition of $(x_n)$ diverge is $\forall l \in \mathbb R,\exists \epsilon>0,\forall N\in\mathbb N, s.t. \exists n\geq N,|x_n-l|\geq\epsilon$.

What is the definition of $(x_n)$ do not converge to $l$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the defintion of divergence, instead of for all $l$. It is just for the $l$ you are intersted in. and it should be there $\exists \epsilon$, instead of $\forall \epsilon$